# Android UI shows RadioButton as selected, although it is not

Tags: android, radio-button

When my UI is recreated on orientation change, I use `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to access custom data I stored to fill the dynamic parts of my layout.

I have a RadioGroup which has two RadioButtons and is already defined in the XML file. The XML automatically makes the first one selected.

When an orientation change happens and the SECOND RadioButton is selected, everything seems to work fine; the second RadioButton is still selected in the UI.

But `RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` says the first RadioButton is selected. And I actually WANT the first one to be selected. But nothing changes when I call `rb1.setChecked(true)` - second one still shown as selected, and still the RadioGroup tells me the first one is selected (now it would make sense, but it's not shown).

This is REALLY strange behavior, does anyone have tips?

(edit)
Parts of my code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.itemselected);
    (...)
    radioGroupServingType = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupServingType);
    (...)

    RadioButton radioOwnServing = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioOwnServing);
    RadioButton radioUseServing = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioUseServing);

    radioOwnServing.setOnClickListener(this);
    radioUseServing.setOnClickListener(this);

    //FIXME WTF
    Log.d("", radioOwnServing.isChecked()+"/"+radioUseServing.isChecked()+" own/use checked");
    radioOwnServing.setChecked(true);
    Log.d("", radioOwnServing.isChecked()+"/"+radioUseServing.isChecked()+" own/use checked");
```

If I select radioUseServing in the UI and change the orientation, the log says `true/false own/use checked` both times - although radioUseServing is shown as selected in the UI.

By the way, logcat also outputs

```
W/asset(4040): deep redirect failure from 0x0103003e => 0x02060007, defStyleAttr=0x0101007e, defStyleRes=0x0103001a, style=0x00000000
```

when changing the orientation, sometimes multiple times. I haven't found anything with google on what that means.

Comment: I just did a workaround for the problem by removing the two RadioButtons from the RadioGroup, creating two new RBs and adding them instead, so that the RBs in the xml are only placeholders. This works, but is kind of dirty and doesn't solve the underlying problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already spoke with you on IRC, but I believe that if you get the view, and post a runnable to it that will call .setChecked(), this will in effect cause the setChecked call to occur at the proper time, and thus avoiding having called setChecked before the view hierarchy was ready for it.
Something like this:

```
final View myRadioButton  = findViewById(R.id.myradiobutton); 
myRadioButton.post(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { myRadioButton.setChecked(true); }
    }
);
```